# rake db:migrate : Could not find nio4r-2.1.0 in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

i have setup a rails application on windows 10 and going to migrate database but i am getting issue

```
rake db:migrate
Could not find nio4r-2.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

i have update and install blundler

anyone have any idea why this is happning

gem_make.out shows me:

```
You have to install development tools first.
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:588:in `try_cpp'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1095:in `block in have_header'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `block in checking_for'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:944:in `checking_for'
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1094:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

what i have missed in it.

Comment: i have already install devKit... Error is :    rake db:migrate
Could not find nio4r-2.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Finally i have resolved the issue, i was using power shell .. and it was not working .. now using cmd and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the development kit of Ruby for windows. Go to the following link, https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and download the mentioned/latest version of Ruby.

If the problem still persists, feel free to comment on this answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. i have already installed "For use with Ruby 2.0 to 2.3 (x64 - 64bits only)"

ruby -v shows me    ==   ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: main Error :   rake db:migrate
Could not find nio4r-2.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have resolved the issue, i was using power shell .. and it was not working .. now using cmd and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the system's `rails`. You must run `gem install rake` and then run `rake db:migrate`.